# Azure Pipelines - Passing Cert as Variable Fails

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Troubleshooting question.

Can anyone give me a clue why the below code won't work? The first task verifies in `openssl` just fine, but the second one fails.

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Bash - Convert Test Cert from Base 64 and save as variables
  name: TestCertConvert
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      openssl genrsa -out "cert.key" 4096
      openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key "cert.key" -sha256 -days 365 -out "cert.crt" -subj "/CN=foo.com"
      manual_cert_decoded=$(cat cert.crt)
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MANUAL-DECODED;issecret=false]$manual_cert_decoded"

      # Verify the cert using openssl
      openssl x509 -text -noout -in <(echo "$manual_cert_decoded")

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Verify test certs can be read
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |                
      openssl x509 -text -noout -in <(echo "$(MANUAL-DECODED)")
```

The second task fails with this output:

```
Could not read certificate from /dev/fd/63
Unable to load certificate

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your YAML sample, you are passing multiple line cert(cert.crt) to the variable.

In this case, the next task can only get the first line of the variable.

For example: it will only pass the value: **-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----**

[image]

Azure DevOps doesn't support Multi-line variable when using logging command to set the variable. Here is a suggestion ticket: [Multiple lines variable in Build and Release](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/multiple-lines-variable-in-build-and-release/365667)

To solve this issue, we need to convert the value of the cert to base64 type. Then decode the variable value in the next task.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  name: test
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      openssl genrsa -out "cert.key" 4096
      openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key "cert.key" -sha256 -days 365 -out "cert.crt" -subj "/CN=foo.com"
      manual_cert_decoded=$(cat cert.crt)
      echo  $manual_cert_decoded
      export CERTIFICATE=$(echo "$manual_cert_decoded" | base64 -w 0)
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MANUAL-DECODED;]$(echo $CERTIFICATE)"
      # Verify the cert using openssl
      openssl x509 -text -noout -in <(echo "$manual_cert_decoded")

- bash: |
   export CERTIFICATE=$(echo "$(MANUAL-DECODED)" | base64 -d -w 0)
   openssl x509 -text -noout -in <(echo "$CERTIFICATE")
  displayName: 'Bash Script'
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks for the response!